# Charles and Proxyman won't show any websocket traffic when creating one with URLRequest, iOS, Swift

Tags: swift, networking, websocket, http-headers, charles-proxy

I’m fighting with *Charles* (and Proxyman), *web sockets* and *URLSessionWebSocketTask*. I’m setting up a web socket with a *URLRequest*, setting a http header field and then creating a web socket task from a *URLSession*.
Here’s what I’m trying to do code-wise:

```swift
self.urlSession = URLSession(
 configuration: .default, 
 delegate: self, 
 delegateQueue: OperationQueue()
)
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("\(someValue)", forHTTPHeaderField: "a-http-header-field")
self.webSocketTask = self.urlSession?.webSocketTask(with: request)
self.webSocketTask?.resume()
self.listen() // Set up .receive and read messages from the web socket
```

When I run the app in the iOS simulator I can clearly see that the web socket is up and running using breakpoints, logs and I’m receiving messages and sending data.
However, on Charles and Proxyman, I see no traffic related to this web socket. I can see many other network requests though.
The interesting thing is that when I create a web socket using a *URL* as follows:

```
let url: URL = ...
self.webSocketTask = self.urlSession?.webSocketTask(with: url)
```

then I can magically see the web socket’s traffic.
I also tried to omit setting up a header value in the request, and just using the request:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
self.webSocketTask = self.urlSession?.webSocketTask(with: request)
```

I get the same result: no traffic.

to sum up, the problem is that when I set up a web socket using a *URLRequest* I see nothing on Charles/Proxyman concerning that web socket's traffic; while using a *URL* I can.

Why is this happening?
Could it be that Charles/Proxyman cannot intercept and decode effectively such web socket?

I would expect to see the websocket's traffic no matter how a *URLSessionWebSocketTask* is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced it again and I believe that it's a bug from Apple.

Creating a `URLSessionWebsocketTask` from `URLRequest`, causes the Websocket never goes through the HTTP Proxy. It goes directly to the Internet.

```swift
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
self.webSocketTask = self.urlSession?.webSocketTask(with: request)
```

✅ To fix it, I highly recommend using the [Atlantis framework](https://github.com/ProxymanApp/atlantis) from Proxyman.

It performs the Method Swizzling underhood to capture and send the Websocket data to Proxyman app. Work with `URL` or `URLRequest`.

Here is the [example app](https://github.com/NghiaTranUIT/WebsocketWithProxyman).

[image: Capture Websocket from URLSessionWebsocketTask]